# .NET LINQ2XML parsing XML and getting all nodes with specifc name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to migrate into using Linq2XML after using some other ways of parsing XML like following:

```
 string xml = "//some xml file here";
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xml);
 for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("Title").Count; i++)
 {
  // get all elements values that have this tag name
 }
```

I would like to now translate this into LINQ2XML and to basically write a query against this test XML file..

Can someone help me out? Would I have to store it into an array of Titles or something like that ?

Comment: You can use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. The example code contains a LINQ query. `Load(TextReader)` your file and then query.

Comment: You can use [`XContainer.Descendants(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @dbc and what goes after that? I could really use an example since I'm completely new with linq2xml

Comment: Your question doesn't include what you are doing after querying the `XmlDocument` so I can't really say what to do after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XContainer.Descendants(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [`XElement.DescendantsAndSelf(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300437(v=vs.110).aspx) on the root element):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("Title"))
{
    // element is an element with the name "Title" -- process it however
    // you want.
}
```

Note that, if you are modifying the document by adding or removing elements inside the `foreach` loop, you will need to snapshot the list like so:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("Title").ToList())
{
    // element is an element with the name "Title" -- process it however
    // you want.
}
```

Finally, if you want to find elements with just a specific [local name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname(v=vs.110).aspx) and ignore namespace, you can do:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Title"))
{
    // element is an element with the local name "Title" -- process it however
    // you want.
}
```